# How to make color of centers the same color of clusters?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, colormap

i have two methods one for drawing the centers for the cluster

```
def draw_roh_delta(self, rho, delta, center, plot):
        plot.scatter(rho, delta, label='rho-delta', c='k', s=5)
        plot.set_xlabel('rho')
        plot.set_ylabel('delta')
        center_rho = rho[center]
        center_delta = delta[center]
        np.random.seed(6)
        colors = np.random.rand(len(center), 3)
        plot.scatter(center_rho, center_delta, c=colors)
        plot.legend()
```

and others for drawing the cluster

```
def draw_cluster(self, title, cluster, halo, points, plot):
    cluster_points = dict()
    colors = dict()
    np.random.seed(10)
    for k, v in cluster.items():
        cluster_points[k] = points.loc[cluster[k], :]
        colors[k] = np.random.rand(3)
    for k, v in cluster_points.items():
        plot.scatter(v.loc[:, 'x'], v.loc[:, 'y'], c=colors[k], alpha=0.5)
        plot.scatter(v.at[k, 'x'], v.at[k, 'y'], c=colors[k], s=np.pi * 10 ** 2)
```

I need to make the color of the centers the same color as the clusters instead of creating them randomly. can someone help, please?

**EDIT**

```
def draw_roh_delta(self, rho, delta, center, plot):
    plot.scatter(rho, delta, label='rho-delta', c='k', s=5)
    plot.set_xlabel('rho')
    plot.set_ylabel('delta')
    center_rho = rho[center]
    center_delta = delta[center]
    color= ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow','orange','purple']
    plot.scatter(center_rho, center_delta, c=color)
    plot.legend()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `plot` function to draw points, which returns a `list[Line2d]`. You just need to take out the first element and call its `get_color()` method obtains the color drawn this time.

I drew my result of kmeans clustering as follow:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, center in enumerate(centers):
    color = ax.plot(*center, '*')[0].get_color()
    points = data_set[labels == i]
    ax.plot(*points.T, 'o', c=color)
```

Unfortunately, to do this, you may need to blend the two methods together, or let the first method return all colors to the second method.

**EDIT**

I would solve it like this:

```
def draw_rho_delta(self, rho, delta, center, plot):
    # ...
    self.colors = []
    for c_rho, c_delta in zip(center_rho, center_delta):
        color = plot.plot(c_rho, c_delta, 'o')[0].get_color()
        self.colors.append(color)

def draw_cluster(self, title, cluster, halo, points, plot):
    # ...
    for (k, v), color in zip(cluster.items(), self.colors):
        p = points.loc[v, :]
        plot.plot(p.loc[:, 'x'], p.loc[:, 'y'], 'o', c=color)
        plot.plot(p.at[k, 'x'], p.at[k, 'y'], 'o', c=color)
```

I don't know the type of your `plot`, so I assume it's `matplotlib.pyplot.Axes`, and I assume that the order in which you draw the centers is consistent with the order in which you draw the clusters.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying but how can i make the first method return the colors to the second method or what should i do after that , please

Comment: excuse me can you have a look at my edit post. I make the color consistent in the first method. how can I take them to the second method to be applied on the clusters

Comment: @sammo Consider changing the statement of drawing `center` to `plot` function combined with `for` loop. Each iteration adds the color to a list and returns. The second method applies each color in list to the corresponding cluster (however, this can only be used by `plot`, not `scatter`).